# JTS Geometry to GML3.1 encoding

Tags: geometry, geotools, gml, jts-topology-suite

I searched all the internet and I didn't find a solution to my problem. I want to convert a JTS geometry to a GML3.1 geometry. Geo tools says that have support but the have not (please check encode method from GML class, where the GML3 version is not checked). Their examples on official page are not working at all because ... guess what ... exactly, encoding for GML3 is not implemented (I also tried with 13-RC1, not only with 12.2). Any other suggestion to do this ? Or I will end up by implementing something on my own that will generate the GML3.1 xml ?

PS: I am just a little desperate. :)

Comment: This output from GeoServer is generated with GeoTools and it should be in GML 3.1. Do you mean that it is not? http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?request=getfeature&version=1.1.0&service=wfs&typename=topp:states&count=1&outputformat=text/xml;%20subtype=gml/3.1.1